# on submit not running validation script

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

If this question has been answered elsewhere I do apologize (I did check before hand, however couldn't find an answer).

The problem seems to be that the *validation script* is not running when I click *submit*.

Here is the code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
 document.forms[0].onsubmit = validForm;
}
function validForm() {
 var allGood = true;
 var allTags = document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName("*");
 for (var i=0; i<allTags.length; i++) {
  if(!validTag(allTags[i])) {
   allGood = false;
  }
 }
 return allGood;
 function validTag(thisTag) {
  var outClass = "";
  var allClasses = thisTag.className.split(" ");
  for (var j=0; j<allClasses.length; j++) {
   outClass += validBasedOnClass(allClasses[j]) + " ";
  }
  thisTag.className = outClass;
  if (outClass.indexOf("invalid") > -1) {
   thisTag.focus();
   if (thisTag.nodeName == "INPUT") {
    thisTag.select();
   }
   return false;
  }
  return true;
  function validBasedOnClass(thisClass) {
   var classBack = "";
   switch(thisClass) {
    case "":
    case "invalid":
     break;
    case "reqd":
     if(allGood && thisTag.value == "") {
      classBack = "invalid";
     }
     classBack += thisClass;
     break;
    default:
     classBack += thisClass;
   }
   return classBack;
  }
 }
}
```

```css
input.invalid {
 background-color: yellow;
 border: 1px solid red!important;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" id=quote-generator>
  <input type=number step=1 placeholder=Distance id=distance class=reqd autofocus>
  <input type=text value="Running Cost" id=fuelPrice onFocus="this.blur()" readonly><span id=aside title="This value is calculated by the AA & is updated every 3 months">*</span>
</form>
<input type=submit value="Submit" form=quote-generator onclick="formQuote()">
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ajikanfan/jrx5uhju/).

Comment: formQuote() is not defined so it shows object expected error

Comment: and why would you need onclick? you already bind `document.forms[0].onsubmit = validForm;` on window.load event?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call function `formQuote`, which is not defined, change it to `validForm`, which is used in your code to validate the form

see this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jrx5uhju/1/

**code:**

```
  <input type=submit value="Submit" form=quote-generator onclick="validForm()">
```

Answer (score 0):

ReferenceError: formQuote is not defined

```
<input type=submit value="Submit" form=quote-generator onclick="validForm()">
```

Comment: Why same answer again ? already  Naeem Shaikh is given an answer as same as that of you , and he had made it first then why same answer again ?

Comment: I was trying same thing and in matter of 1-2 minutes bith answer were posted.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV he probably did not notice, happened to me too couple of times.

Comment: No problem, you can include more explanation about the problem , or you can clarify it your own your way

Comment: Thank you everyone for being patient with a noob. I'm still learning about this whole Javascript thing.